# JSON to XML conversion using spring for Multiple models

Tags: java, json, xml, spring

I have a use case in which i get a JSON from a service and i need to create a custom XML out of it.

JSON we receive

```
[StudentDetails(Name=Lucky, Section=B, Subjects={}, StudentId=4, Hobies=MCCDDVP1, Principal=Mary), 
StudentDetails(Name=Brendon, Section=A, Subjects={}, StudentId=1, Hobies=MCCDDVP1, Principal=Mary),
StudentDetails(Name=Gina, Section=A, Subjects={}, StudentId=2, Hobies=MCCDDVP1, Principal=Mary),
StudentDetails(Name=Monica, Section=A, Subjects={}, StudentId=3, Hobies=MCCDDVP1, Principal=Mary),
StudentDetails(Name=Stephen, Section=B, Subjects={}, StudentId=5, Hobies=MCCDDVP1, Principal=Mary),
StudentDetails(Name=Justin, Section=B, Subjects={}, StudentId=6, Hobies=MCCDDVP1, Principal=Mary),
StudentDetails(Name=Sony, Section=B, Subjects={}, StudentId=7, Hobies=MCCDDVP1, Principal=Mary)]
```

XML to create

```
<Class>
    <Section>A
        <Subject>Maths
            <Student>Brendon
                <Gender>M</Gender>
                <RollNumber>1</RollNumber>
            </Student>
            <Student>Monica
                <Gender>F</Gender>
                <RollNumber>2</RollNumber>
            </Student>
        </Subject>
        <Subject>English
            <Student>Brendon
                <Gender>M</Gender>
                <RollNumber>1</RollNumber>
            </Student>
            <Student>Gina
                <Gender>F</Gender>
                <RollNumber>3</RollNumber>
            </Student>
        </Subject>
    </Section>
    <Section>B
        <Subject>Science
            <Student>Justin
                <Gender>M</Gender>
                <RollNumber>4</RollNumber>
            </Student>
            <Student>Sony
                <Gender>F</Gender>
                <RollNumber>2</RollNumber>
            </Student>
        </Subject>
        <Subject>English
            <Student>Stephen
                <Gender>M</Gender>
                <RollNumber>5</RollNumber>
            </Student>
            <Student>Lucky
                <Gender>F</Gender>
                <RollNumber>3</RollNumber>
            </Student>
        </Subject>
    </Section>
    <PrincipalName>Mary</PrincipalName>
</Class>
```

Now i did create the model class for each attribute like below

**Class.java**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Class{

    private List<Section> section;

    
    public List<Section> getSection() {
        return section;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setSection(List<Section> section) {
        this.section= section;
    }
}
```

**Section.java**

```
public class Section{

private Subject subject;

public Subject getsubject() {
            return section;
        }
    
        public void setsubject(Subject subject) {
            this.subject= subject;
        }
}
```

and so on for all the inner attributes.

Now i am not sure how to create the XML out of these models and get the values from the given JSON as per the XML we need to render using spring boot.

Below is the solution i tried

Created 2 more class just to start with.

**Subject.java**

```
public class Subject {

    private Student student;

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    public Subject(Student student) {
        super();
        this.student = student;
    }

    private Map<String, List<Student>> studentSubjectMap;

    public Map<String, List<Student>> getstudentSubjectMap() {
        return bPartnerEndPointMap;
    }

    public void setstudentSubjectMap(Map<String, List<Student>> studentSubjectMap) {
        this.studentSubjectMap = studentSubjectMap;
    }

}
```

**Student.java**

```
public class Student {

    private String gender;
    private int rollNumber
    
    //Getter and Setter
    //All Args constructor
        
}
```

From the json values i set the values in the classes and then tried to marshal the **Class.java** as below

**Main.java**

```
Subject subjectList = new Subject((Student.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy
                (Student::getSubject, 
                        Collectors.mapping(Student::getRollNumber,Collectors.toList())))));
        
Section section =  new Section(subjectList);
Class class =  new Class(section);

JAXBContext jc;
        try {
            jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Class.class);  // line #1
            Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            m.marshal(combinedXml, file);
            m.marshal(combinedXml, System.out);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            log.error("Error while creating XML", e);
        }
```

After doing this i am getting below error at line #1

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:445)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:277)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1123)
```

Below are the ways i tried to set the values in the Pojo
a. Using @Builder
b. Using @Autowiring
c. Using "new" Keyword.

Getting the same error only number of annotations in error changes.
I am not sure what am i missing.

Comment: Before to step into the implementations: your XML is malformed. The names (for example, "Math", or "Gina") should be either an attribute or a node. Please, tell us how you'd want to format the XML so we can give some suggestions

Comment: @GregorioPalamà - Those would be a node

Answer (score 0):

You need to

- create a `JAXBContext` from your model class
- Create a `Marshaller` from your `JAXBContext`; then
- call the `marshall` method, passing in your model object

An example that will return an XML string is below...

```
public String getXMLString(Class obj) {
   JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Class.class)
   Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
   m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
   StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
   m.marshal(obj, sw);
   return sw.toString();
}
```

Comment: I need to understand how can i create the xml based out of json in the format that i need. What attributes and how models should be drafted.